# How to remove an element from array of objects during copy to another array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

After api calling I am getting an array of objects like this:

```
[{
 name: 'Apple',
 price: 120,
 buying_price: 80
},
{
 name: 'Banana',
 price: 20,
 buying_price: 10
},
{
 name: 'Orange',
 price: 100,
 buying_price: 70
}
]
```

Now I want to copy this result to another variable but don't want to copy `buying_price`. How can I do that?

Copy Variable will be like this:

```
[{
 name: 'Apple',
 price: 120
},
{
 name: 'Banana',
 price: 20
},
{
 name: 'Orange',
 price: 100
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let copied = original.map(v => {return {name: v.name, price: v.price}});

/*
Object destructuring
let copied = original.map(({name, price}) => ({name, price}));

*/
```

Comment: `.map(({name, price}) => ({name, price}))`

Comment: Or `.map(({buying_price,...r}) => ({...r}))`